# Multiple where and orwhere inside closure laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi there I am trying to use closure so that I can have have nested where clause in my query. But the problem I think is it doesn't let me build more than two where clauses because when I try to continue the build with an `orWhere`, it gives out an error. **Can you help me resolve this and why is it returning an error?**

```
  $filtered_table = $filtered_table->orWhere(function ($filtered_table) use ($splitYearQuarter){
                $filtered_table = $filtered_table->where('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '03' . '%')
                 ->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '02' . '%')
                 ->orWhere('methods.crated_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '01' . '%');
              });
```

**EDIT 1**

Those values should exist in my database I am sure.

[image]

***EDIT 2***
Here's what happens when I comment out the two `orWhere` the values are  returning properly.

[image]

Here's what happens with the regular query I posted, it gives an error
[image]

And this is how I output the query through my console.

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/filterdatacal',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        filters: filter_list,
      },
      success: function(filtered_table) {
        console.log(filtered_table);
        if(filtered_table == ""){
          console.log('empty but success');
        } else {
          //$("#datacal_table").empty();
          //console.log(filtered_table);
          for (var i=0; i < filtered_table.length; i++){
            for (var key in filtered_table[i]){
              if(key == 'method_created_at'){
                console.log(key + " -> " + moment(filtered_table[i][key]).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'))
              } else {
              console.log(key + " -> " + filtered_table[i][key]);
            }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('error');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I honestly don't know the error message since I am returning the built query through ajax.

Comment: Maybe the problem is when you use `function ($filtered_table)` and then `$filtered_table = $filtered_table` try to change for `function ($query)` and `$filtered_table = $query`

Comment: @user827391012 check your console to view error message

Comment: @nerea i don't get it is this what you meant? `$filtered_table = $filtered_table->orWhere(function ($query) use ($splitYearQuarter,` `$filtered_table){
                $filtered_table = $filtered_table->where('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '03' . '%');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can skip the assignation

```
$filtered_table = $filtered_table->orWhere(function ($filtered_table) use ($splitYearQuarter){ 
    $filtered_table->where('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '03' . '%') 
    ->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '02' . '%') 
    ->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '01' . '%'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know why it was making that behavior (maybe because there's something going on under the hood which I am not familiar with) but when I tried this query, it went through.

```
 $filtered_table = $filtered_table->orWhere(function ($filtered_table) use ($splitYearQuarter){
                $filtered_table = $filtered_table->where('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '03' . '%');
                $filtered_table = $filtered_table->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '02' . '%');
                $filtered_table = $filtered_table->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '01' . '%');
              });
```

Comment: I think that you can skip the assignation ` $filtered_table = $filtered_table->orWhere(function ($filtered_table) use ($splitYearQuarter){ $filtered_table->where('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '03' . '%') ->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '02' . '%') ->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $splitYearQuarter[0] . '-' . '01' . '%'); });`

Comment: yeah thank you, your suggestion went though. I now prefer what you've written. if you'd like put that as your answer and I'll happily choose it.

Comment: Posted as answer :)